# Auto copy files when added to network share

Tags: samba, scripts, clipboard, scanning, share

I have a network share on my system to which our plotter scanner sends its scanned files. How can I write a script to automatically copy newly added files to another folder?

Answer (score 2):

`cron` and `rsync` would be my tools of choice. I'm going to assume you've mounted this network share through naultilus or another method. There are other, better ways to mount things than through Naultilus (especially for scripting purposes) but I'll leave that up to you:

Open a terminal and run `crontab -e`. You might be asked to select an editor (`nano` is easiest). In there you want to add a new line that looks something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * rsync -avz ~/.gvfs/remote/path/ ~/scans/
```

Control-x, then y to save.

That will sync everything down from  `~/.gvfs/remote/path/` to `~/scans/` every five minutes. It won't re-download things that haven't changed. Of course you'll want to edit the paths and you might want to change the timing for the cron statement. You might want to limit it to in-hours, or run it more often.

Answer (score 0):

- Let `$share` contain the path to your "share (...)to which our plotter scanner sends its scanned files"
- Let `$afolder` contain the path to your "another folder"

My simplisctic approach would be to keep a list of files in `$share`. Write a script that checks if the files currently in `$share` are in this list. It not, they must be new and should be moved.
Then add this script to `cron` thus running it regularly.

Let `$filelist` contain the path to said filelist.

Script (not tested - just a template):

```
#!/bin/bash

...variables as discussed....
filelist=/some/path/to/the/aforementioned/filelist

find "$share" -type f >> /tmp/foundfiles
while read fnd; do  #walk files in folder
    isinlist=""
    while read listitem; do  #walk listitems
        if [ "$fnd" -ef "$listitem" ]; then
            echo "$fnd Allready in list."
            isinlist="inlist"
        fi
    done < "$filelist"
    if [ ! -n "$isinlist ]; then
        echo "$fnd" >> "$filelist"
        cp "$fnd" to "$afolder"
    fi
done < /tmp/foundfiles
rm /tmp/foundfiles
exit 0
```

There are tools that do that for you, like rsync. But maybe you want to add some custom-funtionality.